# Three cards are randomly selected, with replacements from a deck of 52 cards.

Tags: probability, statistics

Three cards are randomly selected, with replacements from a deck of $52$ cards. Find the distribution table of the random variable $X$ representing the number of spades among the three cards obtained.

Could someone help me figure out how to answer this? I'm really stumped.

$$P(X=0) = \frac{39\choose{3}}{52\choose{3}}= \frac{9139}{22100} = \frac{703}{1700}$$

$$P(X=1) = \frac{{13\choose{1}}{39\choose{2}}}{52\choose{3}} = \frac{(13)(741)}{22100} = \frac{9633}{22100} = \frac{741}{1700}$$

$$P(X=2) = \frac{{13\choose{2}}{39\choose{1}}}{52\choose{3}} = \frac{(78)(39)}{22100} = \frac{3042}{22100} = \frac{117}{850}$$

$$P(X=3) = \frac{{13\choose{3}}}{52\choose{3}} = \frac{286}{22100} = \frac{11}{850} $$

Comment: You need to write down the probability, that given three cards , none/one/two/three of them are spades. Can you write down the probability that if you pick one card, it is a spade? That's a starting point.

Comment: I've edited the post to reflect the work I've done. Would this be correct?

Comment: Yes, I think this would be fine. The calculations are also correct.

Comment: Are you also user @TaljanaD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be correct if you were drawing without replacement.  $39 \choose 3$ is the number of ways to get three non-spades drawing without replacement.  A good check is to add the probabilities and see if they sum to $1$.  They do.  If you have done something wrong it is very unlikely that they will.

For drawing with replacement, the chance of getting a spade is fixed at $\frac 14$, so the chance of no spades is $\left(\frac 34\right)^3=\frac {27}{64}$

Comment: Is this with or without replacement? Because her question says with replacement so is the answer still correct?

Comment: @TaljanaD:  I missed that.  No, it is not.

Comment: How would one find the rest? what is the formula?

Comment: @TaljanaD:  to get one spade, you also need two non-spades and there are three orders you can draw them in.

Comment: for x=0 i got 27/64 for x=1 i have 9/64, for x=2 i got 3/64, and for x=3 i have 1/64. but the total of all of them don't give 1 what am i doing wrong. I used this formula:

Comment: @TaljanaD:  for $x=1$ and $x=2$ you missed the three different orders you can draw the cards in.  That multiplies those by $3$